# how can I change my photo on here?

Tags: support, gravatar, profile-picture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

I searched but couldn't find a post, how can I change my photo, my openID is my myspace URL which has many photos, how do I show one here?

Comment: If that email address doesn't work, why do you use it? You don't need your email address to match your OpenID.

Comment: Whoops...maybe I should check the dates first next time. :/  On second thought, will I get kicked if I vote to close the FAQ as duplicate? \*eg\*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register for a [gravatar](http://gravatar.com) using the same email address you use for your account here. Gravatar is a service to share your avatar across multiple sites (wordpress blogs, SO/SF/SU, some forums). It works by putting your avatar at a URL like `http://gravatar.com/avatar/`*md5 of email*

Comment: Ahh thats a bad setup, im my case anyways.  I use my myspace email, that email does not work anymore however I still use it to login so this is a pain,.  Also I tried using gravatar.com and there signup seems to be broke or doesnt ever send email to my working email address

Comment: Well, unfortunately, the email address you want to use has to be verified (which is not possible if it doesn't work), so you can either change your email, or go without an avatar.

Comment: If that email address doesn't work, why do you use it? You don't need your email address to match your OpenID.