# How is gravatar set on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do avatars work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-avatars-work)

What is Gravatar? How to set an image to my profile? I keep trying, but can't set an image to my profile. How to do that? How to work on it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Overflow (and its sisters) uses the Gravatar service to locate and display user avatars. This means that you do not have to (and cannot) upload an avatar directly to Stack Overflow, but instead you upload it at gravatar.com, making it available to any Gravat enabled website.

Upload your avatar here: [Signup to get your own gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/site/signup/)

---

If you believe you have already registered with Gravatar for you e-mail address, but no icon shows up on Stack Overfow, try the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Go back to the [Gravatar signup form](https://en.gravatar.com/site/signup/).
2. Enter the e-mail you have registered in the form and hit the button.
3. If you have successfully registered in the past, you should see a red box with this text:

   > The email address user@example.org already belongs to an account in our system.
   > The current gravatar associated with it is: [image]
4. If the red box does not show up, continue with your registration. If the box shows up, does it display a miniature of your correct avatar (like mine above)?
5. Right click the miniature and choose "copy image location" - paste in a text editor. Do the same on your (defunct) avatar at Stack Overflow. Are the two URLs identical?
6. If no: you have probably used different e-mail addresses on Gravatar and Stack Overflow.

Comment: how created the account with the id what i have registered with stackoverflow. but its doesnt work. is anything to set on the stackoverflow site specicfically.

Comment: @Praveen - Stack Overflow uses an MD5 hash of the e-mail address they have for you when requesting a gravatar - did you use the same address for gravatar as Stack Overflow? If so, then just wait a while, sometimes it takes a while for caches to clear.

Comment: @Praveen: What Dominic said, and I have added a short trouble shooting guide to my answer.

Comment: thanx a lot you all guys.

Comment: What if I had registered on stackoverflow with different email, but then changed to another one and used email for gravatar that new one too? It seems stackoverflow does not see my picture and only shows `identicon`.