# How to Change or Add a Gravatar?

Tags: support, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

I've been trying to change my Gravatar picture for a few weeks now. I try every time I visit SO.

I can browse to my PC, and select the file.

Gravatar displays my picture, a small preview and a large preview, with the instructions, `Crop your photo using the dotted box below`

However, there does not appear to be anything that allows me to crop! I can drag over the image, but that just selects the image.

The only instructions I find on the page are, "The previews above show what your new gravatar will look like after clicking Crop and Finish" ...there's no Crop **OR** Finish!

Also, there is no 'FINISHED' link ...or button!

If it helps, my SO account is linked using my Google ID - and my Google ID has the image I am trying to use as my SO Gravatar!

Comment: I can see your gravatar just fine.

Comment: Also: I have tried this both on Google's Chrome and Internet Explorer (huh! Just realized there's no simple way to tell what version if IE I am running!).

Comment: IE version: alt-H to show the help menu, About.

Answer (score -2):

http://en.gravatar.com/site/signup/

Comment: HINT: I'm already signed up. In fact, I already have a gravatar displayed.

Comment: Question is: How do I change the PICTURE? The Gravatar website seems to be broken, in that its `Cropper Box Control` does not show up.