# How to change my profile picture in this site?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-picture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

Hi everyone,

How can i change my profile picture in this site?

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com is the place for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/393708, Change picture.

Comment: See here for general instructions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar

Answer (score 2):

Create a [gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/) and add the email address you used there in your SE profile