# How long does it take for chat profiles to update?

Tags: support, chat, profile-sync

Following scenario:

1. user registers, has 1 point
2. user visits chat, notes he cannot post because of only 1 point and needs 20
3. user goes back to SO, answers a question. gets enough points to chat
4. user goes back to chat, but his profile still shows 1 point

Now my questions:

- How long does it take for the profile on chat to update?
- Is there a way to force updating?

Update:
Logging in and out did not help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chat profiles sync once an hour.

A moderator can trigger a refresh, but generally, just wait a bit.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is there a way to force updating?**

Users can force update their chat profile on Chat.SE (not on Chat.SO or Chat.MSE  ) by re-linking their parent profile from the chat profile.

[image]