# Is 21 not enough reputation to go to chat?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How long does it take for chat profiles to update?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95423/how-long-does-it-take-for-chat-profiles-to-update)

I recently tried to help this user on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751944/how-to-execute-unix-commands-through-windows-cygwin-using-java), and we got in a longish exchange about how to solve this. Eventually the reminder to move the discussion into chat appeared, but the user had only 16 reputation, so this was not allowed.

Then I got the brilliant idea to upvote the question - now Martin has 21 reputation, as this screenshot shows. But still, the "move-to-chat" function refuses working, saying that Martin has not enough reputation:

[image: not enough reputation?]

I checked the [Chat's FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq), which quite clearly says that we need 20, not any more. I reloaded the browser tab quite some times.

In case this is a browser problem, I'm still using Opera 11.50 (here on OpenSUSE).

As a more general point, why show this *do you want to move* link at all if it then is not allowed?

Comment: *"As a more general point, why show this do you want to move link at all if it then is not allowed?"* -- Because it teaches people how the system works. If you do not present the link to a user that doesn't have enough reputation, they will think it is always OK to chat in the comments, and they will never see the "not enough reputation" message.

Comment: It's possible that chat doesn't update its acknowledgement of the user's reputation immediately, so it won't recognize the user as having sufficient reputation until the next update interval. That's speculation, though

Comment: @Robert: Then maybe the system could show the *Please avoid ...*, but not the *Would you like* part? Or something like *If you Martin had 20 reputation, you could move this discussion to chat.*

Comment: @Grace: If so, then the update interval should be documented somewhere. (It seems to be at least half an hour, since it still does not work.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Chat syncs on an hourly basis, I'll see if I can pull up the relevant Meta post. **Edit**: [How long does it take for chat profiles to update?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95423)

Comment: @Tim: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know.