# Why can I not post in chat rooms on Stack Overflow? My reputation is 26, and it says I need 20

Tags: support, reputation, chat

I have 26 reputation points. When I go to a chat room, it says I have to have a reputation of at least 20 to talk. Why can't I post in the chat room, then?

I asked a question about a JavaScript problem, and I think it may have gotten buried. I attempted to go to the JavaScript chat room, and it appears I cannot post there either.

Comment: My fault. The thing is, I didnt know what was causing the problem (that it was my profile, and not another issue). Thanks for your help everyone! Speedy service!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc's bump didn't seem to work, so I changed the parent account of [your chat account](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20587/visyoual) to your Programmers account and then switched it back to your Stack Overflow account. It updated to show your current rep (36) so you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

We cache your profile for an hour - I guess you got a lot of those points recently?

I've given it a nudge - it now knows your current stats, etc.

Comment: @Peter IMO your edit is invalid - it wasn't used as part of a *list* of other items, which I see as key here.

Answer (score 1):

Chat profiles are in a separate system.

They take an [hour to update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95423), so just be patient and you'll soon be able to chat!