# Not enough rep for chat?

Tags: bug, comments, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for chat profiles to update?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95423/how-long-does-it-take-for-chat-profiles-to-update)

I am on this question: [Selecting option in select field does not trigger ajax script in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404997/selecting-option-in-in-select-field-does-not-trigger-ajax-script-in-google-chrome/7407106#)

And I would like to continue in chat and I get this message:

[image]

But the OP has 21 rep! he should be able to chat!

Now the OP clicked the link and it worked for him, but why did it not work for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My money's on caching. Chat rep is updated once an hour, if I recall.

That user only hit 21 rep 25 minutes ago, so it may be another half hour or so before chat recognizes it.

Comment: It recognized it for the OP though

Comment: @Neal What do you mean? Do you mean on [SO]? The chat tracks rep a little differently than the sites themselves.