# What is the minimum reputation required to chat?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

I tried to find the minimum reputation required to chat with a person, As want to chat with a person having 6 reputation in all. I know it's a minimum requirement, But don't know what is that. Help?

Also I suggest that to be around **6** as many user got stuck in those first question and the need a discussion on that, but the can't actually, due to this reputation requisite.

Comment: @Mat Thanks that helped.. But wasn't easy to found with my mind set, (to chat). :)

Comment: It's written on the big fat banner you get every time you go to chat...

Comment: Tried to find a question on meta..

Comment: @rptwsthi Everything there is to know about SO's privileges is here: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: @rptwsthi not trivial, but [searching for "reputation required to chat"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=reputation+required+to+chat&submit=search) returns [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126865/a-user-with-1-reputation-in-chat) as the third result and the minimum is clearly mentioned there.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges and https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat. These are accessible either by clicking through from the privilege panel currently on profile pages, or by visiting the help center and searching for "privileges".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [20 points](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat) for all sites.

To find out how many points are required for *any* privilege, visit the sites' `/privileges` page. You can reach it from the dropdown next to your name in the top bar.

[image: privileges link in dropdown]

20 points is really low, I don't see any need to have that lowered any further. From the privilege page:

> We can't allow anonymous participation on chat, so we require a small bit of parent site reputation to ensure that chat is reserved for active, engaged members of the community.

Comment: Why don't I see a "audit" link?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Because I'm special? Golly, never noticed that one. It leads to `/reputation`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters any chance you installed some script that is adding that link?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Bingo, it's the [SE Modifications -- Username autocomplete in comments, inline revision source, and utility links](http://stackapps.com/q/2138) extension.

Comment: @kiamlaluno see above comment, no magic here. ;)