# Let users refresh their chat profiles

Tags: feature-request, chat, profile-page, user-interface, profile-sync

Meta post *[How long does it take for chat profiles to update?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95423/317948)* says it can take up to an hour. This can be quite annoying for a new user who joins chat and then wants to customise their appearance. Please add a button where one can refresh one's profile using the same technology as what the moderators can use. There is no need to bother moderators with mundane tasks like this.

If it is too resource intensive to allow this freely, add in an appropriate time-based quota, like we have it with posting many chat messages in a short time span and changing ones username.

Comment: What benefit would that introduce? Can you elaborate about that point a little bit more please?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Because we have to take care about SE developers time used in a wary way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ People currently have to ask moderators to do this a lot, if they don't want to wait an entire hour to get their new identity pushed out.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 _"... to wait an entire hour  ..."_ That might even not justify mod time spent.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's often a few hundred chat messages that will be attached to the old identity in the transcript.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 And what's really harmful about that? Just don't change your identities so frequent.

Comment: "This can be *quite annoying for a new user* who joins chat and then wants to customise their appearance" does this happen that often? I still don't see a convincing reason for this request. Just let them know  it's cached, so it needs some time to propagate to chat.

Comment: That option for mods from my understanding is more for when syncs fail (especially when a suspension doesn't carry over from the main site for whatever reason) rather than to expediate name changes. After it has happened though (and it's normally a little bit of time but not from experience around an hour) then refreshing the page or coming back to the page will show updated details anyway... Aside from a few odd previous user names in @ replies... not sure it's really that big a deal...

Comment: wait. We can speed things up? Damnit. THIS CHANGES ... actually very little.

Comment: Also... Since name changes are limited to once per 30 days (okay - it's slightly more complicated given your first day/two on the site and 15 min grace window but in general)... It only needs to happen once and if that takes a small bit of time in chat to reflect that.... It's not the end of the world...

Comment: Anyway... Instead of requesting something *new* meant for when the process doesn't work.... Why not make it a request to make the current process more robust and as close to immediate as it can be? Then there's no new UI, no new rules about its use and concerns about any abuse and users don't have to care about knowing something is there when as far as they're concerned it should have just happened anyway?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Since this feature already exists for moderators, I doubt making it available to profile owners would require time-consuming changes.

Comment: @Dennis Sometimes you would be surprised how hard it can be to transfer _"already existing features"_ into completely different contexts. Let the SE devs decide about that please (decision would take 6-8 weeks).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Fair enough. But wouldn't that imply that we shouldn't downvote proposals because they *might* take up too much dev time?

Comment: @Dennis except it's in a known UI position, with known permissions required and no rate limits. You'd have to find somewhere to put it for the user, change permissions to allow 
the user/mod to do it and consider rate limiting if not by a mod. Plus some documentation on it explaining why to use it. Seems a lot more work than just fixing /speeding up the sync or sticking with flagging for mod if it borks (and sometimes it's been known to bork in a way that CMS/devs have to look :p)

Comment: @Dennis https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6880627#6880627

Comment: Ideally - the option shouldn't even need to be there for mods. It's a "click this and it might fix what's not worked - but it might not do anything anyway" thing :p

Comment: @Jon Well, just pop a message that let's the user know, that it had done something (just like shown with the DVs  given by users without the appropriate prvileges) :-D

Comment: If you go and "change" your parent profile to the site it was already set it seems to instantly refresh your profile.