# Change avatar image by clicking on it in user profile

Tags: feature-request, gravatar, profile-picture

After having read through the [meta.SO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar) (obtained by going to meta.SO and searching) to how to change my avatar image, I think it would be simpler if in the user profile of any SO network site you could just click on the avatar image and be brought to the instructions page or gravatar.com .

Comment: **Why?** How often do you change your gravatar? This seems like an unnecessary gimmick, rather than a useful feature.

Comment: It's just one more click away via the `Edit` link amongst your profile information.  I agree with Cody, there's no reason to change a UI feature for something that's not going to save a lot of people a lot of time on a regular basis.

Comment: +1 for `obtained by going to meta.SO and searching`

Comment: Ah, I somehow managed to miss the edit link, and the giant "CHANGE PICTURE" that results when you click it.

Comment: Yeah, we've all been there, don't sweat it.

Comment: I can't create gravatar because I can't get e-mail from this site (there's no mail in spam). I've send message to gravatar but they haven't respond. I want to change my picture and I can't - this should be done by simple click and selecting image from PC.