# How can I add an image to my profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, gravatar, profile-picture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

When I try to add an image to my profile, I get redirected to gravatar. How can I add an image to my profile?

Comment: Do you mean on _this_ site? If so, this belongs on meta - but is still a badly asked question.

Answer (score 3):

Should be asked on meta I'll answer in case its moved.

You need to set up an account on gravatar and upload your image there. Then use the email you give gravatar in your profile. Give it a few mins/hours(not sure what the correct time is). Then your picture will display on all accounts.

Comment: Thanks! My issue was that I have been trying to get off of Gmail but my entire StackExchange is setup under my Gmail account and so I had my other email address in there.