# can you use an avatar if you registered using the open id?

Tags: discussion, openid, profile-picture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

I have registered to stackoverlow using my open id and can't see how to upload an avatar, so is that possible? if yes, how?

Comment: @JeremyBanks I know how to change my avatar but the thing is (as iglvzx said) The avatar is tied to your Gravatar account - but you cannot register to gravatar using open id -That's why I'm asking the question lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The avatar is tied to your [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com) account (if you have one).

More info on Stack Overflow deciding to use Gravatars: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/gravatars-identicons-and-you/

Comment: i have a gravatar  but you can't register to gravatar using open id THAT"S WHY I"M ASKING THE QUESTION LOL

Comment: Try changing the email address on your user profile to one associated with your Gravatar account. That is how I got mine working. I use OpenID as well.