# How can I set my My profile picture in StackOverflow?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

I want to set My profile picture in my StackOverflow account . I have tried it using Gravator but it's not working for me.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set an email address on your account. Gravatar works by associating a picture with your email address so you need to assign that address to your account.

Comment: Ok Let me check..

Comment: yeah got it..thanks..:)