# How to change avatar on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

Can I change my avatar for my Stack Overflow profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to your account (click on your name at the top of the page) then click on edit and it will display your user details and the avatar.   I believe there is a minimum reputation that you have to reach before you can change it but I could be mistaken.   in any event if you can change it, it will say Change Picture under the avatar.  That will take you to Gravatar to change/create your picture

Answer (score 1):

One way is to setup a [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com) account with the same e-mail you used for your StackExchange profile.