# How are Stack Overflow's default profile pictures generated?

Tags: discussion, images, algorithm, design, gravatar

Anyone else wonder how the default profile pics for Stack Overflow are generated? It must be generated dynamically as it shows random patterns. Can anyone show an implementation of the algorithm in Java?

Comment: It's not random, it's based on the email. Same email will give same picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generated profile picture is called a [gravatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41278/170230), read about in the linked answer. And for generating it in Java, as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4720536/201359), you could take a look at [jgravatar](https://github.com/ralfebert/jgravatar).