# How come some people on the 5th Anniversary blog post have picture icons and some don't?

Tags: support, blog

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/

Some people were able to upload pictures and I was wondering how to do that? I see no way of logging in and the only available way to post is to leave a comment at the bottom with Name, Email, and Website.

At first I thought you had to have a website and it crawls your website for an icon but some people without links to a website have a profile icon.

Comment: Those icons are Gravatars.  http://gravatar.com. Some people don't have a Gravatar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the blog uses [Gravatar](https://gravatar.com/) to populate the image of the user based on their email address assuming they provide one.

Also, the Stack Exchange network of sites also can use Gravatar image [as your profile image on all of the sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41278/215013) if you want to do that.