# How to change my Area 51 pic?

Tags: support, area-51, profile-picture

I know how to edit the user and select "change picture" But, when I click on "change picture", I am redirected to gravatar!

The duplicate answer is outdated, since other users on Area 51 have pics[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFk8M.png)

Also the problem described in the question marked as a possible duplicate differs from the one described here. It appears the other user made the change, but it didn't take effect.

Comment: That's right, Area 51 use only Gravatar, like Stack Overflow was in its first two years of existence. They never updated Area 51 beyond that. (code wise, it's frozen in time for 6-7 years)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The information in the answer seems outdated , since many other users have pics! See my edit.

Comment: Well, they just created Gravatar account and changed their picture there. Not sure what you ask? The answer to  the dupe clearly says "In the meantime, it only supports Gravatar pictures and you'll have to use Gravatar.com to change your profile picture on Area51."

Comment: There are full details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar), see under "For Gravatar:" section.

Comment: Oh, I see! I assumed gravatar only provided gravatars!

Comment: You mean identicons, and no, that's just the default