# Accidentally made an anonymous post with my real e-mail

Tags: support

[Creating and authenticating Salesforce Marketing Cloud Integration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294406/creating-and-authenticating-salesforce-marketing-cloud-integration)

I created this question and didn't want to log-in (LastPass was infuriating me) so I gave it a fake name and my old e-mail. However, the photo shows my avatar anyway. Can I merge that post into my already existing account, or perhaps make the original question anonymous?

Comment: Either would probably need staff, and the contact link at the bottom. Merging the accounts seems like the nice way to go, since you can follow up on said post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar), courtesy of: "[What is the X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/282094)".

Comment: It does. I used the `Contact` button to submit a ticket.